# Printing the vowels and the vowel count in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I will have to **define a function** that takes a person's **full name** and finds the total number of vowels in that input. And I need to output every vowel including the total
number of vowels found. If the name does not contain any vowel then my function should print
“No vowels in the name!”. **Two sample inputs and their corresponding outputs are given below:**

**Sample input:**
(Steve Jobs)

(XYZ)

**Sample Output:**

Vowels: e, e, o. Total number of vowels: 3

No vowels in the name!

I know it is quite a simple program, but I am facing some difficulties in printing an output as shown in the Sample Output. Here's my incomplete code:

```
def vowels(full_name):
    
    for i in full_name:
        count = 0
        if i == 'a' or i == 'A' or i == 'e' or i == 'E' or i == 'i' or i =='I' or i == 'o' or i == 'O' or i == 'u' or i == 'U':
            count += 1
            print(i, end= ',')
            
    print('Total number of vowels: ', count)
```

How can I write a clean program to get the expected output? I'm really lost at this point

Comment: You say: "output as shown in the Sample Output." Could you please provide us your Sample Output?

Comment: Instead of multiple `or`s you could go with `if i in "AaEeIiOoUu"`, which is a lot shorter. And to make that even more readable, create a variable `vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu"`, so you can write `if i in vowels`

Comment: rajah9 It's written in bold..

Comment: You could also go with a `filter`. And rename that `i` to something meaningful like `char`

Comment: If `i` is a vowel add it to a list (lets say `lst`). `', '.join(lst)` for then printing these vowels. A simple if else to see if there are or are not vowels in the list (or the count you store).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things that may be helpful: As the comments have already pointed out, your long chain of `or`s can be shortened by using `in` to check for substring membership:

```
>>> "a" in "AEIOUaeiou"
True
>>> "b" in "AEIOUaeiou"
False
>>>
```

You can use `filter` to create a collection of vowels - only retaining those characters which are vowels:

```
def is_vowel(char):
    return char in "AEIOUaeiou"

vowels = list(filter(is_vowel, "Bill Gates"))
print(vowels)
```

Output:

```
['i', 'a', 'e']
>>>
```

You know that if `vowels` is empty, you can print `"No vowels in the name!"`. If it's not empty, you can print your other message, and use `str.join` on `vowels` to print the vowels, seperated by commas:

```
print(", ".join(vowels))
```

Output:

```
i, a, e
>>>
```

The number of vowels found is just the length of `vowels`.

Comment: Maybe an explanation, that `bool([]) == False` and then OP can go from there. +1 anyway; I think this explains the principle very well

Answer (score -1):

```
vowels = "aeiou"

def is_vowel(char):
   return char in vowels

def count_vowels(word):
    vowels = [char for char in word if is_vowel(char.lower())]
    return len(vowels)

print('Total number of vowels:', count_vowels("Steve Jobs"))
```

Comment: You don't need `vowels` to be a list, just use a string; it's iterable and immutable

Comment: The text output is still missing; if you include it and explain what you did, this might be a good answer